# Use query 2 in query 1 to get all data inside one query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have 3 tables :

*hinteractions (id, name...)
*effects (id, name...)
*hinteractions_has_effects (hinteractons_id, effects_id)

I might have one to many effects in a hinteractions et one hinteraction might have one to many effects, that's why I have this join table.

I have this Eloquent query :

Query 1 :

```
$informations_plante = DB::table('herbs')
        ->select('herbs.name as hname', 'herbs.sciname', 'herbs.id as herbid','hinteractions.id as hinteractionid','hinteractions.note as hinteractionnote','hinteractions.force_id','targets.name as targetname', 'forces.name as force_name')
        ->leftJoin('hinteractions', 'herbs.id', '=', 'herb_id')
        ->leftJoin('forces', 'forces.id', '=', 'force_id')
        ->leftJoin('targets', 'targets.id', '=', 'hinteractions.target_id')->where('herbs.id', $id)
        //I would like to use the query 2 here to select effects.name with hinteraction.id used in this query to get effects' name in this query (I might have one to many).
        ->get();
```

Query 2 :

```
$hinteractions_has_effects = DB::table('hinteraction_has_effects')
                     ->select(DB::raw('effect_id, hinteraction_id','effects.name'))
                     ->where('hinteraction_has_effects', '=', hinteraction.id (from the query 1))
                     ->get();
```

With query 1, I retrieve some informations like hinteractions_id.

I would like to use those hinteractions_id and use them in the query 2.

The best way will be to merge both queries (1 and 2) to get only one Eloquent query.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Try below query and let me know if this is what you're looking for -

```
$informations_plante = DB::table('herbs')
        ->select('herbs.name as hname', 'herbs.sciname', 'herbs.id as herbid','hinteractions.id as hinteractionid','hinteractions.note as hinteractionnote','hinteractions.force_id','targets.name as targetname', 'forces.name as force_name', 'effects.id as effects_id', 'effects.name as effects_name')
        ->leftJoin('hinteractions', 'herbs.id', '=', 'herb_id')
        ->leftJoin('forces', 'forces.id', '=', 'force_id')
        ->leftJoin('targets', 'targets.id', '=', 'hinteractions.target_id')->where('herbs.id', $id)
        //added below lines
        ->leftJoin('hinteraction_has_effects', 'hinteraction_has_effects.hinteractons_id', '=', 'hinteractions.id')
        ->leftJoin('effects', 'hinteraction_has_effects.effects_id', '=', 'effects.id')
        ->get();
```

HTH!